# Unknown attribute 'user_id' with devise nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the Devise gem to authenticate users. I have a User model and an Address model relation where each User `has_one :address` and each address `belongs_to :user`. When I try to register a new user I get the following error on page load: `unknown attribute: user_id`. The trace points to the line `<% resource.build_address...` seen in my view.

If I just delete that line from my view the page will load but none of my nested form fields show up.

In Rails console I can create and save an address then use that saved address as an attribute for a new User that will save.

The view is as follows:

```
<% resource.build_address unless resource.address %>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Your email", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm password", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :favorite_cuisine, placeholder: "Favorite cuisine", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
    <%= f.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>
      <%= address_form.text_field :street_one, placeholder: "Street", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
      <%= address_form.text_field :street_two, placeholder: "Street #2", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
      <%= address_form.text_field :city, placeholder: "City", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
      <%= address_form.text_field :state, placeholder: "State", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
      <%= address_form.text_field :zip, placeholder: "zip", class: 'input-block-level' %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My User model:

```
has_one :address, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
:favorite_cuisine, :username, :address

validates_presence_of :email
validates_presence_of :address
```

My Address model:

```
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :city, :state, :street_one, :street_two, :zip, :user_id

validates_presence_of :city
validates_presence_of :state
validates_presence_of :street_one
validates_presence_of :zip
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Can you verify in your schema that addresses has a user_id field? (I bet it does not).

Comment: You are correct, addresses does not have a user_id field. How should I structure my migration to add user_id to addresses and have it reference User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToAddresses
```

Then edit the file, and

```
def change
  add_column :addresses, :user_id, :integer
end
```

then rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for (resource.address || :address), ... %>
```

Because the form is nested, it should build a new one with form submission to my knowledge.